# Externally hosted private app in play store error

Tags: android, metadata, google-play-console

For externally hosted app in private we have to upload a metadata of the app in the google play console so for that when i am generating metadata the "certificate_base64" is not present. Why "certificate_base64" field is not present in the metadata? without that it not possible to upload metadata in google play console . Below is my metada.

```
{
 "package_name": "com.xxxx.xx",
 "version_code": "1",
 "version_name": "1.0' compileSdkVersion='34' compileSdkVersionCodename='14",
 "minimum_sdk": "26",
 "uses_permission": [
  {
   "name": "android.permission.INTERNET"
  },
  {
   "name": "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
  },
  {
   "name": "com.shreesiddhi.staff.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION"
  }
 ],
 "application_label": "Xxx",
 "icon_filename": "res/E4.xml",
 "uses_feature": [
  "android.hardware.faketouch",
  "android.hardware.wifi"
 ],
 "file_size": 4488730,
 "file_sha1_base64": "++dVUYNmX6MnO/xxxvU/djN2tis=",
 "file_sha256_base64": "Ovyx7lqIaT5wIky2uuZLPSgEY20QIh+qE=",
 "icon_base64": "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",
 "externally_hosted_url": "https://xxx.in/COMMON/shreesiddhi/app_apk/app-debug-demo.apk"
}
```